# Jenkins throws ClosedInterruptExceptions

Tags: jenkins

We run a resonably large Jenkins Server. with 200 + jobs ran at different times.
Recently as the number of jobs have grown we encountered an exception which is thrown that fails the jobs instantly.I can not see why this would happen intermittently (mostly noticed at busier times)

any idea ?

We are on Jenkins 1.565 latest stable version.
Here is the trace:

```
FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:41)
    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:174)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:742)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:168)
    at $Proxy61.join(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:956)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:137)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:756)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:159)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1706)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:232)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:299)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:805)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:69)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SocketChannelStream$1.read(SocketChannelStream.java:35)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
    at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using?  There is a bug in 1.560 (and possibly earlier) that is patched in 1.575.  Basically, when you have a lot of jobs, the start time of the next job on the master, after the initial request is made to the slave,  occasionally exceeds the timeout of the slave so the slave closes the connection and the job on the master fails.

Comment: Thanks :) I am currently on 1.565.3 which is "apparently" the latest stable one. Do you you have a any link or references ??